# To extract specific information in the stack trace using regular expression

Tags: regex

I encountered a problem at http://regexone.com/example/6?
You can view the problem by clicking the link. 
There was required a regular expression to extract the method name, filename and the line number from a particular stack trace in an android development application.

I used the following regular expression to solve the problem :

```
at widget.List.([a-zA-Z]+).([A-Za-z]+\.java).(\d{3,4}).
```

The expression works for the problem but i don't think its the correct regular expression as there is no hat(^) and dollar ($) included in it.

Comment: If you want to actually solve the problem rather than merely pass the test cases then you also need to take into account that packages can contain multiple components separated by a dot, that all names can begin with an underscore and can contain digits except at the first character, etc.

Comment: You are falsely assuming a regex should contain `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to include the hat `^` and dollar `$` signs, then the regex can be rewritten as:

```
^.*\s+at widget\.List\.(\w+)\((\w+\.java)\:(\d+)\)$
```

Ofcourse, you can still use `\d{3,4}` instead of `\d+` but that'll result in you missing the errors in line numbers less than 100(like 1 to 99).

Similarly, you can use `\w+` in place of `[a-zA-Z]+` or simply, `[A-z]+` will work too.

Comment: Thats a perfect regular expression built by you @Back in a Flash. Good one !